# load two files before ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, asynchronous

I need to load two files for the ajax post request. How do I make sure they are both loaded before the ajax call? The current code is like the following.

```
  if (options.a) {                                                 
    var reader = new FileReader();                                             
    reader.readAsBinaryString(options.a);                                           
    reader.onload = function(evt) {                                            
      data.a = window.btoa(evt.target.result);                   
    }                                                                                                                                         
  }  
  if (options.b) {                                                 
    var reader = new FileReader();                                             
    reader.readAsBinaryString(options.b);                                           
    reader.onload = function(evt) {                                            
      data.b = window.btoa(evt.target.result);                   
    }                                                                                                                                         
  }                
  $.ajax({                                                                     
    url: command,                                                              
    data: JSON.stringify(data),                                                
    type: 'POST',                                                              
    success: function(result, status) { 
      .....
  });
```

Comment: promises is what you need

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in @epascarello's answer, promises would be an easy method to use here.

If you can use native promises, you could do something like this to get rid of the duplicate code and `if`-checks. This also allows for any number of files to be loaded before the `$.ajax()` is executed.

The idea is to add promises to an array and then wait until they have all resolved. The promises will resolve when the filereader is done with the reading.

```
var promises = [];
Object.keys(options).map(function(key) {
  if (options[key]) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(options[key]);
      reader.onload = function(evt) {
        data[key] = window.btoa(evt.target.result);
        resolve();
      }
    });
    promises.push(promise);
  }
});

//Await all promises in array
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(function() {
      //All data read, execute ajax
      $.ajax({
          url: command,
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(result, status) {
            .....
          });
      });
```

Comment: You could suggests that you are not familiar with the concept of the question, adjust your answer or will be downvoted.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Have you tested the code you provided? It works the whey you say? If so, like I said before, could suggests that you are not familiar or is sure that it works. Answ

Comment: The word **could** is an inflection of the word **can**, and is used to express possibility or past ability as well as to make *suggestions* and requests. I will not edit my answer, as it's perfectly valid as it is. Suggest it as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually tricky to do. One possibility is to set a timer to periodically check the status of both files (`data.a`, `data.b`). And instead of calling the ajax function directly, start the timer. Once your timer function determines that they are both loaded, then do your ajax call.

```
if (options.a) {                                                 
    var reader = new FileReader();                                             
    reader.readAsBinaryString(options.a);                                           
    reader.onload = function(evt) {                                            
      data.a = window.btoa(evt.target.result);                   
    }
}  
if (options.b) {                                                 
    var reader = new FileReader();                                             
    reader.readAsBinaryString(options.b);                                           
    reader.onload = function(evt) {                                            
      data.b = window.btoa(evt.target.result);                   
    }
}  

//CHECK THE STATUS OF YOUR FILES EVERY 300 MILLISECONDS
var postHandler = setInterval(postData, 300);

//FUNCTION THAT CHECKS THE STATUS OF FILES, DOES THE AJAX POST, AND CLEARS THE TIMER 
function postData() {
  if (data.a && data.b) {
    clearInterval(postHandler);
    $.ajax({
      url: command,                                                              
      data: JSON.stringify(data),                                                
      type: 'POST',                                                              
      success: function(result, status) { 
        .....
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [promises](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to handle this situation.

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( value1, value2 ) {
    console.log( value1 ); 
    console.log( value2 );
    //make your Ajax call 

});

d1.resolve( "call one" );  //trigger inside of onload a
d2.resolve( "call two" );  //trigger inside of onload b
```